# Modal is not being displayed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Whenever I try to trigger a modal in my application, I find the same situation:
I wrote a console.log line into the ajax .done to display the modal code (which is send by an echo in the back end) and looking at the console (opening the chrome dev tool), the modal code appears to be correct.
Another weird fact is that when I click at the modal button, I become unable to click on any other thing at the webpage.

Below, you can look at my modal code and the structure developed to trigger it.

```
<div id=“modal-data-ideas” class=“modal fade” role=“dialog”>
<div class=“modal-content”>
    <div class=“modal-header”>
        <button type=“button” class=“close” data-dismiss=“modal”>&times;</button>
        <h4 class=“modal-title”><h3></h3></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function ideasTable() {
…
$.ajax({
    …
}
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $(‘#modalIdeas’).html(data);
    $(‘#modal-data-ideas’).modal(‘show’);
}).fail(function() {
    alert(‘fail’);
});
```

}

Ajax always returns done, but the modal.('show') appears to do nothing.

I already included modal classes.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap? Also, include *all* of the modal code. This appears to be a portion.

Comment: bootstrap 4.0.0 I am trying to show any bootstrap modal. When i call $('#modal-data-ideas').modal('show') the html element appears but "invisible". I feel like it is a CSS error, but all my other css bootstrap classes looks fine.

Comment: We can't help if you can't post code to repro the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the element with id "modalIdeas" is undefined. If this is the case, that jQuery will return undefined and then calling

`.html(data)`

on undefined will result in an error.

I would recommend debugging this with your browser console open which should show you that error.

Comment: The element "modalIdeas" is properly defined. Actually, I figured out that modal is opening, but Im not able to look at it (seems like the modal is opened, but not anywhere on the screen).

Comment: I see, couldn't tell from the provided context. Based on the bootstrap documentation, I would suggest wrapping your `<div class="modal-content">` in `<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">` 
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/